# Phpmyadmin access denied, Nginx + php5.6

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx, phpmyadmin

I configured my new application php 5.6 on a new server Ubuntu 16.04, using Nginx 1.10, php5.6-fpm,

When i tried to configure the phpmyadmin to open it using my app url "http://myapp.com/pm", it says Access denied, with folllowing error in my nginx log:

```
2017/05/31 12:39:37 [error] 30267#30267: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: myapp.com, request: "GET /pm HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", host: "myapp.com"
```

My vhost config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/myapp/;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /pm {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }


    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 18000;
    }
}
```

And the phpmyadmin path is:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 612 May 24 17:46 index.nginx-debian.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  22 May 25 17:01 pm -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

> Here are some possible solutions:
>
> 1. In your php-fpm www.conf set security.limit_extensions to .php or .php5 or whatever suits your environment. For some users, completely
>      removing all values or setting it to FALSE was the only way to get it
>      working.
> 2. In your nginx config file set fastcgi_pass to your socket address (e.g. unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;) instead of your server
>      address and port.
> 3. Check your SCRIPT_FILENAME fastcgi param and set it according to the location of your files. In your nginx config file include
>      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$; in the location block where
>      all the other fastcgi params are defined.
> 4. In your php.ini set cgi.fix_pathinfo to 1

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23393266/2604320))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your source post's config file is different than mine, and working on different versions than mine, but i tried those steps and still "Access denied"